# Reporting 988 transactions on tax returns?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, capital-gain

How do you report a 988 transaction on a tax return (on which IRS form) and how do you elect it as ordinary income/loss vs. capital gain/loss?

I believe its covered in: 26 U.S. Code § 988 - Treatment of certain foreign currency transactions

> The foreign currency gain or loss on a 988 transaction is treated as
>   ordinary income or loss unless an election is made to treat it as a
>   capital gain or loss.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably suggest adding it to your [Form 4979 Part II](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f4797.pdf). Otherwise you may consider adding it as additional income on line 21, but I'm not sure how it would work with automatic NIIT calculation. If you calculate it manually - just make sure to add the income to the investment income.

Election to treat as investor should be made **before** making the purchase, so if you didn't make that election - it is too late to do it now.

Comment: Should I be reporting gains/losses as per last day of tax year or only report them after converting the amount to USD (in case I still hold the currency)?

Comment: @JashSayani you report them when you close the position.